# Splitting with different delimiters

Tags: python

i have the following lines im reading from a file

```
# subject, catagory, note
literature,general education,,note: see approved list
social-cultural elective,general education,,note: see approved
```

i want to split these to add to a dictionary later. So i want to split at the comma, the double comma, and the ":" chracter. how will i be able to do this so that the end result appears as

```
{'Literature' : [['general education'],[ 'see approved list']] 'social-cultural elective' : [['general education'],[see approved]]}
```

im using re split and had the "W+" expression but did not work becuase each lines had varying white spaces and other character such as "-", help

Comment: You really need to be precise in describing what you want.  In your example, I see that you also changed the "-" in "social-cultural" to a blank, and removed "note: " entirely twice.  Spell out *exactly* what you want - don't leave anything out.  Otherwise people guess, you say "no", etc etc etc - it gets really tedious ;-)

Comment: yea i accidently left out the dash. and the note does not have to be removed, i just assumed that if you split at " : " everything before is lost so only the text after that character matters

Comment: "if you split at " : " everything before is lost so only the text after that character matters" --> Why don't characters before comma (i.e., literature, general education, etc) get removed also, then?

Comment: `split` doesn't throw any characters away, except for (optionally!) the characters you're splitting *on*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re
splitter = re.compile(r":|,,?")
for line in ("literature,general education,,note: see approved list",
             "social-cultural elective,general education,,note: see approved"):
    print splitter.split(line)
```

That prints:

```
['literature', 'general education', 'note', ' see approved list']
['social-cultural elective', 'general education', 'note', ' see approved']
```

If that's not exactly what you want, edit your question, because that's exactly what you asked for ;-) (i.e. "So i want to split at the comma, the double comma, and the ":" character").

Comment: Woo hoo!  Sometimes we get lucky ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use Python  built-in [split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) function:

```
>>> a_str='social-cultural elective,general education,,note: see approved '
>>> import re
>>> re.split(': |, |\*|\n', a_str)
```

PS: For double commas you can do **[str.replace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)** first

Comment: Is `re.split()` built-in since you have to import it?

Comment: yea i dont understand how it would be done with double commas

Comment: @mathguy54, yes - Python ships with a large collection of modules, and they're all considered to be "built-in".  Why?  Because every Python comes with them ;-)

Comment: @mathguy54 `re` is for Regular expressions

Comment: You can handle single and double commas by changing the `,` in the regexp to `,,?`.  But whether a space "should follow" the comma(s) in the regexp isn't clear, because you haven't described what you want *precisely*.

Comment: @Zach Santiago just use `replace` to remove `,,`

Comment: You should link to the `re.split` docs rather than `str.split`.

Comment: im loking for replace module to see how to use it. any links you recommend?

Comment: @Tim True, fixed that!